# How to change filestore folder to point to a folder in another server instead?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I found in `odoo.conf` file that there is an option `data_dir` in there, which specifies the directory for multiple data storage subdirectories, one of which is `filestore` folder.

It keeps most, if not all, file attachments and images inside the Odoo for each database.

I would like to change this configuration to point to a specific directory in another server entirely. How to do that?

Comment: By setting up a mount on your server pointing to the other server?

Comment: @CZoellner Can you elaborate it as an answer?

Comment: Sorry but that's not my domain, that's why i made a comment. In the end you can mount volumes (linux/unix, windows i dont know...) and that will be "directories" and can be used in the odoo config.

Comment: What about performance ? filestore is used in so many cases like storing session_data that might make problems in navigating.

Comment: @AlesisJoan Right. Performance is also important, but for the sake of this question. I think it is better to see as many proposed solutions as possible then choose the one that is the best of all. Maybe there are other factors too.